# Ubuntu server installer freezes while it should enter the partition area

Tags: server, system-installation

Im trying to install the ubuntu server edition. The install acts normal until the part where it should start the disk partitioner. Is detects hardware, the status are dissapears and then it just sits there with a purple screen. There is no more response from the installer. I tried different version, a different hard disk but all didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas what the next step is? Im installing on the dg33bu intel motherboard.

Comment: Are you installing 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! ... I would like to Let you know I had succes installing. I dont still dont exactly know what went wrong. The way I had succes was using unetbooting on a 1gb stick. I dont know why the cd failed and the live cd usb creator on the same usb failed.thanks for the reactions!